# Silverlight & events

Tags: silverlight-4.0

namespace SilverlightApplication1
    {
        public partial class MainPage : UserControl
        {
            public MainPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

```
            datePicker1.SelectedDateChanged -= datePicker1_SelectedDateChanged;
            datePicker1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
            datePicker1.SelectedDateChanged += datePicker1_SelectedDateChanged;
        }

        private void datePicker1_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("datePicker1_SelectedDateChanged");
        }
    }
}
```

Why message box appears?

Answer (score 0):

datePicker1.SelectedDateChanged -= datePicker1_SelectedDateChanged;
//Defines  you use the RemoveHandler function. you might want to remove event handlers during the application lifetime

datePicker1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today; 
// You are Assigning to Datepicker Selected date

datePicker1.SelectedDateChanged += datePicker1_SelectedDateChanged;
// the event handlers on the relevant object are ready for user-initiated events at run time.

So The Message Box Came .
Third Line You Have Call The Eventhadler That Y it will come